# Python regex parsing on variable

Tags: python, regex

Not sure why this is not matching and not working?  It appears something is wrong with the regex such that it doesn't match even though i tested it out in the online regex tester

```
current_name = "bob[0]"
regex_match = re.compile('%s'%current_name)
if re.match(regex_match, current_name):
    print "matched"
```

Comment: What are you trying to match from that string? The value between `[` and `]`?

Comment: You're trying to match the string `bob[0]` with the pattern `bob[0]\[[.*]]` to  ?

Comment: If you want to put backslashes in a regex pattern without having to double them, make it a raw string - `r'whatever'`.  As it is, your backslash is getting lost, because the following character isn't part of a backslash escape.

Comment: i am trying to do an exact match of the string.    I edited the code but still doesn't work

Comment: @KAM - then why use regex at all? `if current_name == "bob[0]": ...`  will give you an exact match.

Comment: I think the square brackets are causing your problems...

Answer (score 0):

```
current_name = "bob[0]"
regex_match = re.compile('%s'%current_name.replace('[', r'\['))
if re.match(regex_match, current_name):
    print "matched"
```

That opening square bracket was causing issues. this will print "matched"